# refresh view of my fragment after asynctask finished

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a fragment and I want to load some data from server in oncreatView method.

after request and response from server I want to refresh the fragment View if asynctask response was null.that mean I need to change the onCreateView() method of my fragment.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final        
ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

fView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_booklist, container, false);
AsyncTask<String, String, String> p = new GetService(url, new ServiceCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskComplete(String result, int status) {

            Request r = gson.fromJson(result, Request.class);
            if(r!=null){
                //do my jobs 
            }else{
                //I want to set another view for fragment if here happend
            }
return fView;

}
```

pleas help me!

Comment: and what's the issue ?

Comment: i want to generate another view and show it as my fragment view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> after request and response from server I want to refresh the fragment
>   View if asynctask response was nul

the easiest way is to have both views in the layout you inflate in your `onCreateView`, and when the response arrives, you change their visibility accordingly to it. Be aware that you have to change its visibility on the `UI Thread`. If you don't want to have both view in the same layout, you can use an inflater to get a View's object of the view you want to add, and use `fView.addView()` to add it. Also here addView has to run on the `UI Thread`